# Keras: Online CNN-LSTM. Error with batch size specification for Stateful LSTM

Tags: python, video, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I want to make a video event trigger which outputs 1 on detecting a change in event and 0 for other frames. I am using a CNN followed by an LSTM to do that. Both the CNN and LSTM are in the same model and have to be trained together. Each feature frame is encoded by CNN and this output is provided to the LSTM.

The problem is that , in order to process online videos, I need an online LSTM which is stateful and operates on batch size 1. Even after doing so, Keras gives me the error:

ValueError: If a RNN is stateful, it needs to know its batch size. Specify the batch size of your input tensors: 
- If using a Sequential model, specify the batch size by passing a `batch_input_shape` argument to your first layer.
- If using the functional API, specify the batch size by passing a `batch_shape` argument to your Input layer.

I need to know where I am going wrong and what can be the solution.

I have tried including batch size in all the layers. starting from Input layer in the CNN andeven in The LSTM.
The model compiles if i am not using stateful='True' in LSTM and don't mention the batch size

I am attaching the complete code.

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.models import Sequential,Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import LSTM,Input,TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import Activation
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.utils import np_utils




'''
DAP will get triggered whenever it receives a frame with optical flow 
very different from the previous opticalflow.It uses the optical flow
to determine whether a new event has started to occur in the videoframe
or not.

The CNN is responsible for extracting the optical flow. The RNN/LSTM is
used to trigger the event change by tracking the sequence of online
optical flow frames, being feeded from the CNN at every timestep.

NOTE: Keras does not support summary of a TimeDistributed Model without
specifying inputoutput dimension. Hence this coding approach had to be
incorporated , specifying layer names and seggregating the input output
layers. First we  define the model. The separately define the CNN.
Then add the CNN to the model. And then add the LSTM. This is the only
approach to incorporate online video frame (which doesn't require 
specifying the frame no or the third dimension of the LSTM).

An alternate, and perhaps easier to read, approach is to wrap each layer 
in the CNN model in a TimeDistributed layer when adding it to the main 
model.



INPUT: an 80x80 RGB image
OUTPUT: a sequence of 0 and 1s . 

1 implies an event trigger. 0 implies continuation of the current event

'''

model=Sequential()

#--------------CNN----------------------------------------
x_input =  Input(shape=(80,80,3))
c1=Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same' )(x_input)
a1=Activation('relu')(c1)
c2=Conv2D(32,(3, 3))(a1)
a2=Activation('relu')(c2)
p1=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(a2)
d1=Dropout(0.25)(p1)
c2=Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(d1)
a3=Activation('relu')(c2)
c3=Conv2D(64, (3,3))(a3)
a4=Activation('relu')(c3)
p2=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(a4)
d2=Dropout(0.25)(p2)
#FCN-----------------------------------------------------
f=Flatten()(d2)
d=Dense(512)(f)
a5=Activation('relu')(d)
x_output=Dropout(0.5)(a5)
#model.add(Dense(2))
#model.add(Activation('softmax'))
#---------------------------------------------------------
cnn = Model(x_input,x_output)
print("CNN SUMMARY")
cnn.summary()

#-----------------LSTM-------------------------------------
model.add(TimeDistributed(cnn,input_shape=(1,80,80,3)))
#model.add(cnn)
#batch size=1,
model.add(LSTM(128,batch_input_shape= 
(1,512),stateful='True',activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
#----------------------------------------------------------

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
print("DAP summary")
model.summary()
return model
```

Also i need to know if this is the correct approach towards coding an online LSTM.

The overall model should input 1 frame of the video and output a 0 or 1 for that frame, for every frame of the video. (one to one)

Comment: Did you solve this?